# Edit JSON file in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to edit a JSON file to append a value. However, I can't find a way to get the expected result. Given the below JSON:

```
{
   "First": "1",
   "Second": "2",
   "A_lot": [
      { 
         "Address":"Str" 
      },
      { 
         "Fruits" : [ "apple", "orange" ],
         "colors": : [] 
      }
   ], 
   "last": "end 
}
```

I want to add a fruit called banana and my JSON to look

```
{
   "First": "1",
   "Second": "2",
   "A_lot": [
      { 
         "Address":"Str" 
      },
      { 
         "Fruits" : [ "apple", "orange", "banana" ],
         "colors:" : [] 
      }
   ], 
   "last": "end 
}
```

I have search online but I couldn't find anything related.
When I am trying to run this:

```
 var myjson = File.ReadAllText(pathtojson);
 JObject newDeploymentProfileDocument = JObject.Parse(myjson);

 var deploymentProperties = newDeploymentProfileDocument["A_lot"][1];

 var myFruit = "banana";
 deploymentProperties["Fruits"].AddAfterSelf(myFruit);

 File.WriteAllText(myjson, newDeploymentProfileDocument.ToString());
```

I am getting the following error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty cannot have multiple values.

Since I am new to C#, let alone C# and json files, can you please point me what I am missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: cast `deploymentProperties["Fruits"]` to `JArray` and use `Add(...)` instead `AddAfterSelf(..)`

Comment: in addition to @Selvin's comment you can do this to cast and call `Add` `(deploymentProperties["Fruits"] as JArray).Add(myFruit);`

Comment: @E.Shcherbo with this, it works like a charm.
Thanks everyone. Kudos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sent JSON seems is not the correct format. If you mean something like this:

```json
{
  "First": "1",
  "Second": "2",
  "A_lot": [
    {
      "Address": "Str",
      "Fruits": [ "apple", "orange" ],
      "colors": []
    }
  ],
  "last": "end"
}
```

As the others mentioned in comments, just do it like this:

```
    ...
    var deploymentProperties = (JArray)newDeploymentProfileDocument["A_lot"][0]["Fruits"];
    var myFruit = "banana";
    deploymentProperties.Add(myFruit);
    ...
```

**Edited**

If you don't want to change your JSON structure, you can use this:

```
var deploymentProperties = (JArray)newDeploymentProfileDocument["A_lot"][1]["Fruits"];
var myFruit = "banana";
deploymentProperties.Add(myFruit);
```

Comment: Why it's not in the correct format? There is exactly the same JSON in the question as your.

Comment: It was in correct format @E.Shcherbo cough my point. It helped me resolve the issue and get a better understanding. However, thank you for your reply, I appreciate your effort! :)

Comment: Not me actually, [Selvin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/690952/selvin) did this, I just add some notes about how you can cast.

Comment: I mean there are 2 objects in the array that aren't the same. In the main array `A_lot`, index 0 contains `{Address}` and index 1 contains `{Fruits, colors}`.